# How to change value of label in Tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I want to change the text in a label everytime the button is clicked and the command is called. Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from random import *

def background():
    x = randrange(255)
    y = randrange(255)
    z = randrange(255)
    rgb_color = [x,y,z]
    mycolor = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (x, y, z)
    app.configure(bg=mycolor)
    label1 = Label(app, text=rgb_color)
    label1.pack()

app = Tk()
app.geometry("500x400+5+5")
app.resizable(0,0)
app.title("Color Code")
button1 = Button(app, text="Change", command=background)
button1.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

Every time the button is clicked, a new label is created under it. How can I make it change the current label based on the rgb_color?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you want tell me if I am incorrect. The below code creates a new label the first time `background` is called, and modifies it any extra times.

```
from Tkinter import *
from random import *

global num
num = 0

def background():
    global num
    num += 1
    x = randrange(255)
    y = randrange(255)
    z = randrange(255)
    rgb_color = [x,y,z]
    mycolor = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (x, y, z)
    app.config(bg=mycolor)
    if num == 1:
        global label1
        label1 = Label(app, bg = mycolor, text=rgb_color)
        label1.pack()
    else:
        global label1
        label1.config(bg = mycolor, text = rgb_color)

app = Tk()
app.geometry("500x400+5+5")
app.resizable(0,0)
app.title("Color Code")
button1 = Button(app, text="Change", command=background)
button1.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks so much, exactly what I needed. Also, do you know if I can make the background of the button and label transparent or match the background. Looks a little weird with white. Thanks

Comment: @user3150094 yes, change colour same way as you have with the app. See edit.